# How to create a shared link with an expiration date for the item of OneDrive For Business via Rest API?

Tags: office365

I want to integrate our app with OneDrive For Business, I used to create a shared link via rest API. But now I want the shared link temporary, Is it possible for us to set an expiration date for the shared link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Graph API did not document such an API that could achieve this goal, but finally, we get the right API by tracing the OneDrive website.
[image]

Only when you select “Anyone” option, it will prompt a date pop-window. Some people may find that “Anyone” is gray and unselectable at their tenant. That is because this option is by default disabled. We should enable external sharing for SharePoint.
[image]
Of course, for the private site collection, you can set up it in sharepoint admin center. Additionally PowerShell is also available for the configuration.

```
$adminUPN="replace_with_username" $orgName="name_of_sharepoint_prefix" 
$usercredential = Get-Credential -username $adminUPN -Message "type 
password" Connect-SPOService -Url https://$orgName-admin.sharepoint.com - 
Credential $userCredential
#Identify and connect to the desired Site Collection
$siteurl="https://$orgName.sharepoint.com/sites/desired_site_collection"
#Enable External User and Guest Sharing on that chosen Site Collection
set-sposite -identity $Siteurl -sharingcapability 
ExternalUserAndGuestSharing
```

That’s it.  Now check your work (refresh the page/site collection)， “Anyone” option should be available.

After that we are able to create an anonymous shared link with an expiration date Programmatically. I have investigated the relevant API.

- Register an app and assign the below permission.
  [image]
- Get through authentication procedure and acquire access token, you can refer to 
  ADAL
- Invoke the API

```html
POST https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{site}/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle(‘Documents’)/Items(1)/sharelink
Body :  {“request”:{“createLink”:true,”settings”:{“linkKind”:5,”expiration”:”20180504T000000+0800″}}}
```

I notice that only the anonymous shared link supports expiration date. The other options currently have not released such an API or feature.

BTW, I find a free channel to solve Azure and Office365 queries: [aka.ms/devchat](http://aka.ms/devchat). They support online chat and email.